# Jsoup selector notation for CLASSLESS elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, jsoup

The Jsoup [selector-syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) is pretty straightforward for pinpointing any element by id, class or attribute.

But I haven't found (yet) the proper syntax for:

> "find all `<a>` elements that
>   **don't** have a class name (*any* class name)"

Is there special Jsoup syntax for that? or will I have to find all `<a>` elements and check myself whether it has a class name?

Comment: jsoup is Java? Oh crap, I thought it was a JavaScript library and that "soup" was an alliterative pun on "Script" (i.e. based on the letter S). -facepalm-

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, Jsoup is Java. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This CSS selector picks up `<a>` elements without a `class` attribute:

```
a:not([class])
```

Comment: @BoltClock Nice! I will try that ASAP and get back to you on the result.

Comment: @BoltClock 1st update: According to Jsoup's documentation, your suggested syntax should work, but it makes Jsoup crash with: `org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query 'a:not[class]': unexpected token at ':not[class]'` -- I need to double-check what I actually put there.

Comment: @ef2011: You're missing out the `()` around `[class]`.

Comment: @BoltClock OMG you're so fast. Like a lightning bolt. :)

Comment: @ef2011: Which is funny, because the bolt in my name actually refers to nuts & bolts :P

Comment: @BoltClock Your correction eliminated the crash (of course), but now I have to deal with this particular element not always showing up due to page not always being fully rendered by the 10th render... (which is a whole different issue by itself). I am going to accept and give +1 for all answers & comments leading to this.

Comment: @BoltClock BTW, the notation you proposed is called in jsoup.org: `pseudo selector`. (I learned yesterday that accurate terminology is sooooo important)

Comment: @ef2011: Well, if you want to be *very* precise, "pseudo-selector" is a colloquial term; the W3C spec defines two distinct kinds: pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements. `:not()` is an example of a pseudo-class. I think I might be imposing on you by now though :)